# C# | Export datagridview to textfile containing header text values

Tags: c#, datagridview, export

After a button click my function will store data to a `DataGridView` as can be seen here:

Image link: [image: Image link to preview datagridview]

Now the data could be exported to a text file once the user clicks another button which would call the following function:

```
private async Task ExportUserData()
{
    string file_name = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/export.txt";

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file_name);

    for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync("\t" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
        }

        await writer.WriteLineAsync("");
    }

    writer.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Data exported!", "Insta Tool Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

This code would write the following to the textfile:

```
export|undefined|False|False|1329560|False|False|False|False|
person|undefined|False|False|419863|False|False|True|False|
dane|Dane Jasper|True|False|65077|False|True|True|True|
```

**Question:**

How could I add the datagridview header values to the output? So the Output would look like the following:

```
Username: export | Name: undefined | Private: False | Verified: False | Id: 1329560 | Email Sent: False | Valid Phone: False | Email Reset: False | Sms Reset: False
```

I've tried doing it in the following way, which didn't work out:

```
await writer.WriteAsync("\t" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value.ToString() + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - I haven't compiled this.  But I think you want:

```
await writer.WriteAsync("\t" + dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
```